# How to integrate ZF2 with Doctrine Mongo ODM?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

I am trying to integrate zf2 beta3 with doctrine mongo odm (https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule) but no sucess.

How can I install and configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give the steps I have done to integrate zf2 with mongodb doctrine odm

1.Download the mongodb doctrine odm module and place in vendor directory or clone it from github

```
cd /path/to/project/vendor
git clone --recursive https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule.git
```

2.Copy the file from /path/to/project/vendor/DoctrineMongoODMModule/config/module.doctrine_mongodb.config.php.dist, place in your path/to/your/project/config/autoload/ and rename to module.doctrine_mongodb.local.config.php

3.Edit your module.doctrine_mongodb.local.config.php. 
Change the default db

```
'config' => array(
    // set the default database to use (or not)
    'default_db' => 'myDbName'
),
```

Change your connection params

```
'connection' => array(
    //'server'  => 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@<server>:<port>',
    'server'  => 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    'options' => array()
),
```

Change the driver options

```
'driver' => array(
    'class'     => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
    'namespace' => 'Application\Document',
    'paths'     => array('module/Application/src/Application/Document'),
),
```

Add proxy and hydratros config

```
        'mongo_config' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'opts' => array(
                    'auto_generate_proxies'   => true,
                    'proxy_dir'               => __DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/src/Application/Document/Proxy',
                    'proxy_namespace'         => 'Application\Model\Proxy',
                    'auto_generate_hydrators' => true,
                    'hydrator_dir'            => __DIR__ . '/../../module/Application/src/Application/Document/Hydrators',
                    'hydrator_namespace'      => 'Application\Document\Hydrators',
                    'default_db' => $settings['config']['default_db'],
                ),
                'metadataCache' => $settings['cache'],
            )
        ),
```

4.Create a directory named "Document" in /path/to/project/module/Application/src/Application/ where goes your documents mapping and inside "Document" directory, create "Proxy" and "Hydrators" directories.

5.Edit your /path/to/project/config/application.config.php and add 'DoctrineMongoODMModule' to modules array

6.Be sure you have mongo php extension installed otherwise download at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows and copy it to your extension php directory, usually /php/ext. Add the extension line acording the name file extension you have downloaded "extension=php_mongo-x.x.x-5.x-vc9.dll" in your php.ini.

7.Create a document mapping User.php in your document directory application module.

```
<?php
namespace Application\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
/** @ODM\Document */
class User
{
    /** @ODM\Id */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return the $id
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the $name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param field_type $name
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

8.Persist it, for example in your controller

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel,
    Application\Document\User;

class IndexController extends ActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $dm = $this->getLocator()->get('mongo_dm');

        $user = new User();
        $user->setName('Bulat S.');

        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm able to get documents to persist however I'm having trouble retrieving documents. Have you managed to do that?

Comment: @Zoop-Josh What's your trouble? Is it hydrator not found error?

Comment: It was the hydrator error. However since you brought it up I rechecked your instructions and there it was; update the hydrator paths! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'm doing just the same thing. Something like this should work:

Download the module, and place in your vendor folder.

Add the module in application.config.php

Copy module.doctrine_mongodb.config.php.dist to /config/autoload

Edit that config file with your own settings

Change the name of that config file to module.doctrine_mongodb.local.config.php

Create a 'setDocumentManager' method in your controller like this:

```
protected $documentManager;

public function setDocumentManager(DocumentManager $documentManager)
{
    $this->documentManager = $documentManager;
    return $this;
}
```

Place the following in your module's DI config:

```
    'Application\Controller\[YourControllerClass]' => array(
        'parameters' => array(
            'documentManager' => 'mongo_dm'
        )
    ),
```

Create Document classes according to the Doctrine 2 documentation, and the clarification in this question and answer: [Annotations Namespace not loaded DoctrineMongoODMModule for Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222507/annotations-namespace-not-loaded-doctrinemongoodmmodule-for-zend-framework-2)

Finally, use the dm like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $dm = $this->documentManager;

    $user = new User();
    $user->set('name', 'testname');
    $user->set('firstname', 'testfirstname');
    $dm->persist($user);
    $dm->flush();

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Note `module.doctrine_mongodb.config.local.php` should be `module.doctrine_mongodb.local.config.php`

Comment: Hi, It helped me a lot, Thank you. I got it working now. The configuration is a bit complex, I will post here a complete answer to configure it that help the newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Now the default config has changed, could you show an updated method to get this working in ZF2?

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(

        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server'    => 'localhost',
                'port'      => '27017',
                'user'      => null,
                'password'  => null,
                'dbname'    => 'user',
                'options'   => array()
            ),
        ),

        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',

                'driver'             => 'odm_default',

                'generate_proxies'   => true,
                'proxy_dir'          => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',

                'generate_hydrators' => true,
                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator',
                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',

                'default_db'         => null,

                'filters'            => array()   // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class')
            )
        ),

        'driver' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array()
            )
        ),

        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'connection'    => 'odm_default',
                'configuration' => 'odm_default',
                'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
            )
        ),

        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array()
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Currently receiving the error: The class 'Application\Document\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces