# ZF2 with Doctrine Mongo ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i have followed
[How to integrate ZF2 with Doctrine Mongo ODM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273130/how-to-integrate-zf2-with-doctrine-mongo-odm?answertab=active#tab-top)
to setup ZF2 With Doctrine Mongo ODM,

I can save document into mongodb,however i can not find the document using below code

```
$dm = $this->getLocator()->get('mongo_dm');
$result = $dm->find('Item', '4f9ea557eabc88e96f000000');
print_r($result);
```

Here is the error log

```
PHP Warning:  class_parents(): Class Item does not exist and could not be loaded in /var/www/vendor/DoctrineMongoODMModule/vendor/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 347
PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /var/www/vendor/DoctrineMongoODMModule/vendor/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 347
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vendor/DoctrineMongoODMModule/vendor/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 347
```

i already try generate document using

```
./vendor/DoctrineModule/bin/doctrine odm:generate:documents ./module/Application/src/Application/
```

Comment: Did you setup autoloading for your 'Item' class? Because otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Try using namespace class, For example $result = $dm->find('Application\Document\Item', '4f9ea557eabc88e96f000000');

Comment: THanks Rafael , 'Application\Document\Item' is correct

Answer (score 1):

```php
$dm = $this->getLocator()->get('mongo_dm');
$result = $dm->find('Application\Document\Item', '4f9ea557eabc88e96f000000');
```

should fix those problem