# example working config for Doctrine ODM zf2 Module?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm, zfdoctrine

can anyone  please provide an example of driver configuration for reading annotation of documents in Application/src/Application/Document/....
created this
but still doctrine-module odm:schema:create said all collection created but there is no collection in my db

````
    <?php

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '27017',
//                'user'      => null,
//                'password'  => null,
                'dbname' => 'yehja',
//                'options'   => array()
            ),
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
//                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',
//
//                'driver'             => 'odm_default',
//
//                'generate_proxies'   => true,
//                'proxy_dir'          => 'data',
//                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',
//
//                'generate_hydrators' => true,
//                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data',
//                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',
//
//                'default_db'         => null,
//
//                'filters'            => array()  // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class')
            )
   // /   // ),
    //    'driver' => array(
    //        'odm_default' => array(
    //        //   'drivers' => array('Appl   
   //         )
        ),
        'driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'namespace' => 'Application\Document',
            'paths' => array('module/Application/src/Application/Document'),
        ),
        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
//                'connection'    => 'odm_default',
//                'configuration' => 'odm_default',
//                'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
            )
        ),
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array()
            )
        ),
    ),
);```
````

module that im using -> https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these works :

**file : config/ autoload/ module.doctrine-mongo-odm.local.php**

```
<?php


Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '27017',
//                'user'      => null,
//                'password'  => null,
                'dbname' => 'yehja',
//                'options'   => array()
            ),
        ),

        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
//                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',
//
//                'driver'             => 'odm_default',
//
//                'generate_proxies'   => true,
//                'proxy_dir'          => 'data',
//                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',
//
//                'generate_hydrators' => true,
//                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data',
//                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',
//
//                'default_db'         => null,
//
//                'filters'            => array()  // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class')
            )
   // /   // ),
    //    'driver' => array(
    //        'odm_default' => array(
    //        //   'drivers' => array('Appl   
   //         )
        ),

        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
//                'connection'    => 'odm_default',
//                'configuration' => 'odm_default',
//                'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
            )
        ),
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array()
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

and **file :     module/ Application/ config/ module.config.php**
add these lines

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',

                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Document')
            ),
            'odm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Document' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you got the config idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273130/how-to-integrate-zf2-with-doctrine-mongo-odm) but the format changed since then. Here's one i have (dibber being the name of the app - and yes it's PHP 5.4 arrays) :

```
'driver' => [
    'dibber' => [
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
    ],
    'odm_default' => [
        'drivers' => [
            'Dibber\Document' => 'dibber'
        ]
    ]
],
```

This basically means that `Dibber\Document` is the namespace in wich the annotation driver is going to  be used. So for you it would be `Application\Document`.

Comment: What @jhuet says will work. I'll just add that `odm_default` driver is a driver chain, thus it has the `drivers` key, which is an array of normal `AnnotationdDriver`s that it will use. So, as @jhuet has done, define your driver in the `driver` array, then add your new driver to the `drivers` array of `odm_default`.