# Doctrine ODM for MongoDB and Zend Framework 2

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Where is my mistake in the configuration?

I try to implement Doctrine ODM in ZF2 - Have a look to my Configuration File:

```
  namespace Application;
  return array(
      'doctrine' => array(

        'connection' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'server'    => 'localhost',
                'port'      => '27017',
                'user'      => null,
                'password'  => null,
                'dbname'    => 'homeup',
                'options'   => array()
            ),
        ),

        'configuration' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache'     => 'array',

                'driver'             => 'odm_default',

                'generate_proxies'   => true,
                'proxy_dir'          => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace'    => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Proxy',

                'generate_hydrators' => true,
                'hydrator_dir'       => 'data/DoctrineMongoODMModule/Hydrator',
                'hydrator_namespace' => 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Hydrator',

                'default_db'         => null,

                'filters'            => array(),  // array('filterName' => 'BSON\Filter\Class'),

                'logger'             => null // 'DoctrineMongoODMModule\Logging\DebugStack'
            )
        ),

        'driver' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
/*                'drivers' => array(
                    'class'     => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'namespace' => 'Application\Document',
                    'paths'     => array('module/Application/src/Application/Document'),
*/
                    'odm_driver' => array(
                        'class' => 'Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                        'paths' => array(__NAMESPACE__ .'/src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Document')
                    ),
                    'odm_default' => array(
                        'drivers' => array(
                            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Document' => 'odm_driver'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),

        'documentmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'connection'    => 'odm_default',
                'configuration' => 'odm_default',
                'eventmanager' => 'odm_default'
            )
        ),

        'eventmanager' => array(
            'odm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array()
            )
        ),
);
```

Info:

- Used tutorial : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule
- ZF2 Version 2.2.4
- Doctrine dev-master
- MongoDB PHP Driver works (with plain PHP)
- Wastet hours of time & searched the web

**EDIT**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException' with message 'The
>   option "odm_driver" does not have a matching setOdmDriver setter
>   method which must be defined' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\homeup.dev\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Servi‌​ceManager\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 859

It was easier than I thought...
Solution is here:

[example working config for Doctrine ODM zf2 Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016741/example-working-config-for-doctrine-odm-zf2-module?rq=1)

Less is more.

Comment: Edit: Forgott the Error Message... sorry
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException' with message 'The option "odm_driver" does not have a matching setOdmDriver setter method which must be defined' in C:\xampp\htdocs\homeup.dev\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 859

Comment: we are having the same issue , have you found any solution for this ??